# Cascading dropdown for country ,state, city getting from Database in reactjs with core api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to display the cascading dropdown for country,state,city from database.If I click the country,the related state only display. And next Click the state the related city only display.

Answer (score 0):

I have compiled some examples found to give a working example:

You can experiment or Try [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-test-selected-value-jc52f?file=/src/DependentSelect.js:0-1706):

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import data from "./data.json";

function DependentSelect() {
  const [country, setCountry] = useState(null);
  const [lang, setLang] = useState(null);
  const [langList, setLangList] = useState([]);
  const [link, setLink] = useState("");

  // handle change event of the country dropdown
  const handleCountryChange = (obj) => {
    setCountry(obj);
    setLangList(obj.languages);
    setLang(null);
  };

  // handle change event of the language dropdown
  const handleLanguageChange = (obj) => {
    setLang(obj);
  };

  // generate the link when both dropdowns are selected
  useEffect(() => {
    if (country && lang) {
      setLink(
        `https://www.${country.url}/search?q=Clue+Mediator&gl=${country.country_code}&hl=${lang.code}`
      );
    }
  }, [country, lang]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>Dependant dropdown in React - </h3>
      <div style={{ width: 400, marginBottom: 20 }}>
        <b>Country</b>
        <Select
          placeholder="Select Country"
          value={country}
          options={data}
          onChange={handleCountryChange}
          getOptionLabel={(x) => x.region}
          getOptionValue={(x) => x.country_code}
        />
        <br />
        <b>Language</b>
        <Select
          placeholder="Select Language"
          value={lang}
          options={langList}
          onChange={handleLanguageChange}
          getOptionLabel={(x) => x.name}
          getOptionValue={(x) => x.code}
        />
      </div>
      <span>
        <b>Link:</b> {country && lang ? link : "-"}
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DependentSelect;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Its manually you giving the datas..but I want to show and filter the datas from database only.